# Excel 2013: VBA to copy formula from one cell to the next

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I need to copy a formula from Cell A3 to B3 in Excel, using a button to run below macro:

```
Sub Copy()
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = ActiveCell.Formula
End Sub
```

Then with every subsequent click of the button, the formula needs to be copied to the next cell in the range(B3:J3) until the whole range is populated. I do not want to fill the range at once with one click of the button, but rather one cell with each click only as this will happen over a period of weeks, therefore one cell to be populated every week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather your problem is that the code you have only works for cell A3 but you want it to work on the last formula in row 3.

If B3 is blank your code will work but if it isn't, it will just copy A3 again.

If B3 is not blank then you need to copy the last cell in row 3 to the cell to its right.

```
    Sub CopyToRight()
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With WS
        If IsEmpty(.Range("A3").Offset(0, 1)) Then
            .Range("A3").Copy .Range("A3").Offset(0, 1)
        Else
            .Range("A3").End(xlToRight).Copy .Range("A3").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, This works like a charm, much appreciated. May I ask you one more thing, How would I go about converting the previous cell's formula to the value it is displaying just before the the formula is copied to the next cell? E.g the formula returns a value of, let's say 100, I then update a lookup sheet with values which the formula in the next cell will process to say 120 once it is copied to the right. I would like to keep the original value in the previous left hand cell as it will also be updating on entering the new values in the lookup sheet, any ideas how I can manage that?

Comment: That should be posted as a new question.  You can use my code as a starting point and assign the value of the cell being copied to a variable before you do the copying then assign the variable to the cell from which you have copied after copying.  Try it and come back with another question if you can't make it work.  Also, mark the answer as accepted by clicking the box to the right below votes.

Comment: That would be to the left, not right.  Pardon my Lysdexia

Answer (score 1):

One thing has to change, either:

1. the "A3" has to become "B3" on the next iteration or
2. the .Offset(0,1) has to expand to get to the next empty cell.

You could code it either way, if 1, name A3 'CopyCell', then after you copy it right change the named 'CopyCell' to B3.  if 2, you just need to change Offset(0,1) to (0,cols) where cols = the current cols + 1

```
Sub Button_Click()
'
' Button_Click Macro
'

    Range("CopyMe").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = ActiveCell.Formula
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)).Select
    With ActiveWorkbook.Names("CopyMe")
        .Name = "CopyMe"
        .RefersTo = ActiveCell
        .Comment = ""
    End With
'

End Sub
```

In terms of robustness, it's not very good because it assumes that the current cell to copy right is named "CopyMe" and if it isn't, it won't work.

So if someone runs the macro, then deletes the column and tries to run it again, it won't work.

Comment: Thank you kztd, I haven't tried your solution yet as Mark's solution below is doing exactly what I want. But I will give it a go as well.